# how to represent complex json to C# dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I would like to represent/convert complex JSON to C# dictionary.

JSON is

```
{
"58": { "Power": 26, "Mantissa": 58},
"59": { "Power": 27, "Mantissa": 59},
"60": { "Power": 28, "Mantissa": 60},
"64": { "Power": 0, "Mantissa": 64},
"65": { "Power": 0, "Mantissa": 64},
"66": { "Power": 1, "Mantissa": 65}
}
```

I thought it can be represented by Dictionary of Dictionaries in C# like

```
    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>();
```

I am out of ideas how to implement this data structure.
Please help.

Comment: Why you don't use a class for that? Is much cleaner.

Comment: We need to see the result of your attempt.

Comment: +1 for using a class... Also, http://www.newtonsoft.com/ will make things very straight forward for you.

Comment: @Main Why do you want to not use a class? Answering "Why don't you use a class?" with "I would like to not use a class" doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: You could deserialize (using Newtonsoft JSON) to an ExpandoObject, which has a dictionary interface. Honestly, you should just write your own classes to deserialize into. It's cleaner, less error-prone, and any other developers can understand what's going on easily.

Comment: thanks for answers and comments. I did not expect downvote for my question!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.NET will be able to deserialize your json:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,int>>>(json);
```

You were close, but you missed that outer dictionary should have `string` as key type.

---

Though I think using `Dictionary<string,int>` as outer dictionary value type is not very good decision:

- You will lose IntelliSense for `Power` and `Mantissa` values. Other developers will not guess which keys they should look for in the dictionary. And no errors with mistyping *Matnissa* instead of *Mantissa*.
- You will get burden of dictionary internal stuff (buckets for entries, counter for size etc)
- Your code will work slowly comparing to accessing properties of custom object (hashcode of string should be calculated, then appropriate bucked should be selected, and after that you should iterate bucket items to get value from dictionary).

Compare it with custom class usage:

```
public class Number
{
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Mantissa { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing is almost same:

```
var numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Number>>(json);
```

But access to values is much simpler, faster:

```
numbers["60"].Mantissa // numbers["60"]["Manitssa"].Value
```

Comment: @Fabio there is 6 *separate* dictionaries with `"Power"` and `"Mantissa"` keys.

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
public class YourObject{
     public int Power {get;set;}
     public int Mantissa {get;set;}
}
```

After that you can use Json.NET to convert your JSON to a list of YourObject:

```
List<YourObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourObject>>(yourJSONString);
```

Answer (score 0):

its so simple. at first we need a object like this:

```
public class YourObject
{
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Mantissa { get; set; }
}
```

then just try this:

```
    var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, YourObject>>(richTextBox1.Text);
```